# Wordpress Divi theme : mobile menu not working

Tags: wordpress, menu

I got a small problem with my wordpress website.
I got Divi theme on it and the mobile menu only works with the shop page and not opens on the rest of the site.

I tryied to disable/enable plugins one by one, but it still not works.
I havent any console error.

oneonlymtl.co

It's the url of the website.

If anyone has a solution, I'll be very happy.

Thank you,

Franck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source for the page the menu items are not being populated on the mobile menu for the home page that's why clicking on it does nothing.  Do you have a conditional menu setup somewhere?

Comment: Oh I didnt check in the source code. Not really. I just manage the menu in apparearence back office menu.

Comment: I have the same problem, I have conditional menu setup, can you help me on this? this is the site URL http://serviceaide.com @Andrew_Schultz. its a Divi theme with third-party reseller.

Comment: It's the same issue, the mobile menu HTML is not being rendered.  Contact Divi support for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the mobile menu was just populated on the frontpage, not on any other pages.

After some research I found out that I had a script error in my child theme's javascript file which caused the mobile menu from not being created (it gets created via Divi's javascript). The error in my child theme's script.js stopped that copyMenu script from being executed. When I fixed my error, the mobile menu got copied again :)